# How to recognize a Web Control as a Client Object with JQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, web-controls

Can someone help me how to recognize or catch a custom web control with Jquery and access its client functions?

I created a Web Control(.ascx) in asp.net like in the example.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="MyControl" %>

<asp:Panel ID="myPanel" runat="server">
     <asp:TextBox ID="myText" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>

<script type="text/javascript">
     function showMessage(){ 
          var txt = $('<%= this.myText.ClientID %>')
          alert(txt.val());
     }
</script>
```

Then, I want to place this control in a repeater in a web form (.aspx)

```
<table>
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <Pre:MyControl ID="myControl" runat="server" />
 <input type="button" id="myButton" onclient="sendData(this);" />
 </td>
 </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

In the same page, I want to manage my control of the current row where I click the button aside and here's my doubt.

In my function sendData I want to do something like this:

```
function sendData(sender){
 var row = $(sender).closest('tr');
 var ccontrol = row.find(*******) // 1. 
 ccontrol.showMessage(); // 2. 
}
```

1. Here I want to catch my control with Jquery. I can find it by ID like row.find([id*='myControl']), but how can I recognize it as an object.
2. Here I want to call the client function of the current control

---

**EDIT:** When I do this:

```
var ccontrol = row.find("[id*='myControl']");
```

I get this in the developer tools (debug)

```
<div id="myRepeater_myControl_4_myPanel_4">
    <div id="myRepeater_myControl_4_myPanel_4">
    <input name="myRepeater$ctl04$myControl$myText" type="text" value="hello world" id="myRepeater_myControl_4_myText_4">
</div>
 ,
<input name="myRepeater$ctl04$myControl$myText" type="text" value="hello world" id="myRepeater_myControl_4_myText_4">
```

I would be great to know how to get it as an object and have access to the showMessage().

When my control is rendered I can see in the view source that the repeater is showing my control in html and for each control the function showMessage individually. I want to encapsulate it.

Answer (score 0):

Since i can not comment yet im writing it as an answer:
I don't know much about aspx templates, but try looking at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)
I'm guessing it should be something like `onclientclick` property instead of `onclient` so to reference to the click handler of the element.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get whatever control you want using jQuery:

```
var yourControl = $("#yourcontrolid");
```

If you want it as an `object` just do the following:

```
var yourControlAsObject = $("#yourcontrolid")[0];
```

**EDIT:** Updated to answer comment.

**EDIT #2**:

Would it work better if you just included the script function once with an include for your usercontrol (yourusercontrol.js)?  If you look at your `HTML`, isn't the `showMessage` definition showing up over and over?

You could change the `showMessage` function to look like:

```
function showMessage(controlID){ 
    var txt = $('#' + controlID);  // you didn't have the # in your example
    alert(txt.val());
}
```

Then in your `sendData` function:

```
function sendData(sender){
    var row = $(sender).closest('tr');
    var ccontrol = row.find(*******)  // 1.
    showMessage(ccontrol.attr('id')); // 2. 
}
```

Not sure if this is what you are actually looking for but maybe this approach will at least help get you going.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. I want to find my control with JQuery but as an object and as an object to get access the its client-side methods.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My previous update, it showed in the console of Dev tools my control as a simple text but adding the [0] it looks like  "wrapped" but I still can't access to the javascript inside the control. I want to recognize my web control as object in order to access its client behavior.

Comment: I don't see in your example how `showMessage` is tied specifically to your control?  In the `Repeater`, the function script will just be duplicated for each row with a different client ID but the function itself will still be the same.